# Expansion $f(x)=1/(x-1)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How to expand $f(x)=1/(x-1)$ into the form $1/x+1/x^2+1/x^3+...+1/x^n$ for x>1

I know f(x) can be rewritten as $f(x)=\frac{(1-1/x)^{-1}}{x}$.

Next step is to expand $(1-1/x)^{-1}$ to $1+1/x+1/x^2+...$

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the classic geometric series, if $|x|>1.$

Comment: It's not true that $\frac1{x-1}=1/x+1/x^2+\cdots$.  What is true is $\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots$

Comment: Dubussy you are right, it is geometric series, how did I miss that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide numerator and denominator by $x$:
$$
f(x)=\frac{\dfrac{1}{x\mathstrut}}{1-\dfrac{1}{x}}=
\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{x^n}=
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{x^n}
$$
If you don't see it, just write $1/x=t$, so
$$
f(1/t)=\frac{t}{1-t}=\sum_{n\ge1}t^n
$$
Of course the expansion works for $|x|>1$.

Answer (score 1):

No fuss around. You've got $f(x)=1/(x-1)$, that is $-f(x)=\frac 1 {1-x}$ which famously equals $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$.(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series).

Edit: I realize only now the the question asks for $| x| >1$.

$$\frac 1 {x-1}=\frac 1 {x(1-\frac 1 x )}=\frac 1 x\cdot\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\frac 1 x)^k=\sum_{k=\color{green} 1}^\infty \frac 1 {x^k}$$

Comment: Thanks Gyro, your answer is equally useful.